# getting corrupted top size error in a lexer i am making when having more than 10 characters to tokenize

Tags: c, malloc

so i am having an issue i do not know how to fix... basically the lexer has one main function: `tokenize()` (idk if the spelling is even correct). Anyways, at line 50 i am calling malloc to allocate some memory for the tokens which are going to get generated, the size being:

scriptsize * sizeof(struct token). but when i try to allocate more than 10 tokens: the program crashes with `malloc(): corrupted top size`, can you guys help me? thanks and have a good day.

lexer.c

```c
// low level token types: used in early parsing, and tokenizing of the text
enum llt {separator, operator, number, string, identifier, character, newline};

// string representation of low level token types
char * strllt[] = {"separator", "operator", "number", "string", "identifier", "character", "newline"};

const char separators[] = "({[ \n\t,.)};]";
const char operators[]  = "+*&%^/=-";
const char numbers[] = "0123456789.";
const char whitespaces[] = "\n\t ";

struct token {int type; char * value;};

int token_equals(struct token t1, struct token t2)
{
    if(t1.type == t2.type & t1.value == t2.value) {return 1;}
    return 0;
}

// returns pointer to concatonation of the two selected strings
char * stradd(char * base, char * adder, int size_a, int size_b)
{
    char * combined_string = (char *)malloc(size_b);
    for(int i=0;i<size_a;i++) {combined_string[i] = base[i];}
    for(int i=0;i<size_b;i++) {combined_string[i+size_a] = adder[i];}
    return combined_string;
}

// checks if the selected character is in the selected string
int contains(const char * string, char character, int strsize)
{
    for(int i=0;i<strsize;i++)
    {
        if(character == string[i]) {return 1;}
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_token_type(char character)
{
    if(contains(separators, character, sizeof(separators))) {return 0;}
    if(contains(operators,  character, sizeof(operators)))  {return 1;}
    if(contains(numbers,    character, sizeof(numbers)))    {return 2;}
    return 4; // could be a string also
}

// generates a token array out of a text, core function of the lexer
struct token * tokenize(char * text, int text_size, int * size_ptr)
{
    struct token * tokens = (struct token *)malloc(sizeof(struct token) * text_size);
    int tokens_current_index = 0; // next offset for a new token
    char * _identifier       = 0; // used to generate multi-char tokens
    int id_size              = 0; // the size of _identifier
    int line                 = 0; // the current line
    char * strepr            = 0; // string representation of the current line
    int line_size            = 0; // the size of strepr

     for(int i=0;i<text_size;i++)
     {
         // the token type of the current character
         int token_type = get_token_type(text[i]);

         // the token is either a separator, or an operator
         if(token_type < 2)
         {
             // the end of an identifier has been detected
             if(_identifier != 0 )
             {
                 tokens[tokens_current_index] = (struct token){identifier, _identifier};
                 _identifier = 0; tokens_current_index++; id_size = 0;
             }
             // add the newly detected token to the token array, if it is not a whitespace
             if(!contains(whitespaces, text[i], sizeof(whitespaces)))
             {
                 tokens[tokens_current_index] = (struct token){token_type, &text[i]};
                 tokens_current_index++;
             }
             else if(text[i] == '\n')
             {
                 // add a newline token with value strepr (used in error handling)
                 tokens[tokens_current_index] = (struct token){newline, strepr};
                 line_size = 0; strepr = 0; line++; tokens_current_index++;
             }
         }
         if(token_type == identifier)
         {
             // the character is the first letter in the identifier
             if(_identifier == 0)
             {
                 // make the first letter of the identifier the current letter
                 _identifier = ""; id_size = 1;
                 _identifier = stradd("", &text[i], 0, 1);
             }

             // the chatacter is not the first letter in the identifier
             else
             {
                 // append the new letter to the currently generating identifier
                 _identifier = stradd(_identifier, &text[i], id_size, 1);
                 id_size++;
             }
         }
         if(token_type == number)
         {
             // the number is part of an identifier: for example a10
             if(_identifier != 0)
             {
                 _identifier = stradd(_identifier, &text[i], id_size, 1);
                 id_size++;
             }
             // the number is not part of an identifier: for example 100
             else
             {
                 int    dot_amount = 0;  // 1.1.1 causes an error, 1.1 does not
                 char * str_number = ""; // the number being generated
                 int    num_size   = 0;  // the lenght of the number being generated

                 // generate the number token, similar to an identifier generation
                 for(int x=i;x<text_size;x++)
                 {
                     // check if the next letter is a number, if it is not, break
                     int next_token_type = get_token_type(text[x]);
                     if(next_token_type == number || text[i] == '.')
                     {
                         str_number = stradd(str_number, &text[i], num_size, 1);
                         if(text[i] == '.') {dot_amount++;} // used in error check
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         // the dot amount is invalid: for example 1..2
                         if(dot_amount > 1)
                         {
                             printf("syntax error in line %i: in %s\n", line, str_number);
                             exit(-1);
                         }
                         // add the newly generated number token to the token array
                         tokens[tokens_current_index] = (struct token){number, str_number};
                         tokens_current_index++; i--; break; // stop generating number
                     }
                     // add the current character to the strepr of the line
                     if(strepr == 0) {strepr = stradd("", &text[i], 0, 1); line_size++;}
                     else
                     {
                         strepr = stradd(strepr, &text[i], line_size, 1);
                         line_size++;
                     }

                     // update position of the lexer, and update num_size
                     i++; num_size++;
                 }
             }
         }
         if(strepr == 0) {strepr = stradd("", &text[i], 0, 1); line_size++;}
         else if(tokens[tokens_current_index-1].type != number)
         {
             strepr = stradd(strepr, &text[i], line_size, 1);
             line_size++;
         }
     }
     // add identifier to the end of the token array
     if(_identifier != 0)
     {
         tokens[tokens_current_index] = (struct token){identifier, _identifier};
     }
     *size_ptr = tokens_current_index+1;
     return tokens;
}
```

main.c

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lexer.h"

int main()
{
    char chars[] = "if(x == 3) {return false;";
    int size;
    struct token * tokens = tokenize(chars, sizeof(chars), &size);
    printf("%i\n", size);
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
    {
        if(tokens[i].type < 2)
        {
            printf("token at %i:\t(%s, %c)\n", i, strllt[tokens[i].type], *(tokens[i].value));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("token at %i:\t(%s, %s)\n", i, strllt[tokens[i].type], tokens[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

note: the code is inefficient, i know, but i will try to fix this myself later on, since the program does not have to be very efficient right now

Comment: It's unlikely someone will debug so much code for you. You'll either need to reduce this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or better still use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you debug it yourself.

Comment: You malloc size_b chars then fill the string with size_a + size_b. That can't be right.

Comment: stark: thank you so much, i would never have found this (: